A loss and metrics problem while training a cnn model
i'm having a problem with my custom loss and metrics . My purpose is to train a cnn model on images and with the tangente of the angle orientation of the object in my image and i have a column that indicates if the tangente is positive or negative . And at the end i have two outputs one for tangente (regression ) and the second one is (classification ). Now when i write model.evaluate i write down regression as the first thing to appear but it doesn't appear as the first one . And i'm not sure if they re reversed somehow . because i cannot find an explanation for the weird results that i m getting. This is my code :
# Custom loss and metric functions
@keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package="Custom")

def angular_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    angles_true = tf.math.atan(y_true) * 180.0 / np.pi
    angles_pred = tf.math.atan(y_pred) * 180.0 / np.pi
    return tf.abs(angles_true - angles_pred)

@keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package="Custom")
def rmse_degrees(y_true, y_pred):
    a = tf.constant(np.pi)
    angles_true = tf.math.atan(y_true) * 180.0 / a
    angles_pred = tf.math.atan(y_pred) * 180.0 / a
    b = tf.square(angles_true - angles_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(b)
# Define the model
input_image = Input(shape=X_train_images.shape[1:], name='input_image')
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_image)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)  # Intermediate Dense layer
x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)

output_regression = layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', name='reg_output')(x)
output_classification = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='cls_output')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=input_image, outputs=[output_regression, output_classification])
model.summary()
model.save("modelfinal3.keras")
# Compile the model



model.compile(
    optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001),
    loss={
        'reg_output': angular_loss,
        'cls_output': 'binary_crossentropy'
    },
    metrics={
        'reg_output': [rmse_degrees],
        'cls_output': ['accuracy']
    }
)

# Define ModelCheckpoint callback to save the best model
callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("modelfinal3.keras", monitor="reg_output_loss", save_best_only=True , mode='min'),
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='reg_output_loss' , patience = 8 ,mode='min' )
]

# Train the model without validation data
history = model.fit(
    X_train_images,{'reg_output' : Y1_regression ,'cls_output' : Y2_classification} ,
    epochs= 10 ,
    batch_size= 64,
    callbacks=callbacks
)

test_model =keras.models.load_model("modelfinal3.keras", custom_objects ={'angular_loss': angular_loss, 'rmse_degrees': rmse_degrees })
results = test_model.evaluate(X_test_images, {'reg_output' : Y1_regression_test ,'cls_output' : Y2_classification_test },return_dict=True )


print(results)

results
30/30 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 51s 2s/step - cls_output_accuracy: 0.6618 - cls_output_loss: 9.0815 - loss: 14.4716 - reg_output_loss: 5.3914 - reg_output_rmse_degrees: 2806.2744
Epoch 7/10
30/30 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 53s 2s/step - cls_output_accuracy: 0.6401 - cls_output_loss: 8.9781 - loss: 14.7173 - reg_output_loss: 5.7363 - reg_output_rmse_degrees: 2787.8420
Epoch 8/10
30/30 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 51s 2s/step - cls_output_accuracy: 0.6524 - cls_output_loss: 9.0007 - loss: 14.5403 - reg_output_loss: 5.5401 - reg_output_rmse_degrees: 2789.3442
Epoch 9/10
30/30 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 51s 2s/step - cls_output_accuracy: 0.6674 - cls_output_loss: 9.4412 - loss: 14.7438 - reg_output_loss: 5.3030 - reg_output_rmse_degrees: 2844.9971
Epoch 10/10
30/30 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 52s 2s/step - cls_output_accuracy: 0.6610 - cls_output_loss: 9.3189 - loss: 14.7248 - reg_output_loss: 5.4059 - reg_output_rmse_degrees: 2828.9368
11/11 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2s 142ms/step - cls_output_accuracy: 1.0000 - cls_output_loss: 9.4424 - loss: 9.4928 - reg_output_loss: 1.1921e-07 - reg_output_rmse_degrees: 2435.0107
{'cls_output_accuracy': 1.0, 'cls_output_loss': 8.932900428771973, 'loss': 9.235373497009277, 'reg_output_loss': 1.1920930376163597e-07, 'reg_output_rmse_degrees': 2396.7568359375}

Process finished with exit code 0 

I m expecting normal values for metrics cls about 90% and for metrics for reg about 4.
